# My Particle Simulation is Slow and After While Does not work as Intended

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, oop, simulation, matplotlib-animation

The purpose of this code is to watch particles of random positions and velocities interact with each other but after a while when particles are getting very fast they start passing inside each other without colliding. How Can I fix this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


class Particle:
    def __init__(self, color, id=0, charge=1.602E-19, r=np.zeros(2), v=np.zeros(2), rad=0.01, m=1):
        self.id = id
        self.r = r  # Set of the x and y coordinates of the particle
        self.v = v  # Set of the x and y velocities of the particle
        self.rad = rad  # Radius of the particle
        self.m = m  # Mass of the particle
        self.charge = charge * (np.random.randint(0, 2) * 2 - 1)  # Charge of the particle this will be used later


class Sim:
    X=2 #size of the environment
    Y=2
    def __init__(self, dt=0.00005, Np=100):
        self.dt = dt  # Time jump between events
        self.Np = Np  # Number of particles
        self.particles = [Particle(i) for i in range(Np)]

    def coll_det(self):
        for i, particle1 in enumerate(self.particles):
            x, y = particle1.r
            
             # Wall collision handling
            if x - particle1.rad < -self.X / 2:
                particle1.r[0] = -self.X / 2 + particle1.rad
                particle1.v[0] *= -1  # reverse x-velocity component
            elif x + particle1.rad > self.X / 2:
                particle1.r[0] = self.X / 2 - particle1.rad
                particle1.v[0] *= -1  # reverse x-velocity component
            if y - particle1.rad < -self.Y / 2:
                particle1.r[1] = -self.Y / 2 + particle1.rad
                particle1.v[1] *= -1  # reverse y-velocity component
            elif y + particle1.rad > self.Y / 2:
                particle1.r[1] = self.Y / 2 - particle1.rad
                particle1.v[1] *= -1  # reverse y-velocity component

            for j, particle2 in enumerate(self.particles[i + 1:], start=i + 1):
                m1, m2, r1, r2, v1, v2 = particle1.m, particle2.m, particle1.r, particle2.r, particle1.v, particle2.v
                dist = np.linalg.norm(r1 - r2)
                if dist <= particle1.rad + particle2.rad:
                    # Collision handling
                    n = (r1 - r2) / dist  # Normal vector pointing from particle2 to particle1
                    v1_new = v1 - 2 * np.dot(v1 - v2, n) * n
                    v2_new = v2 - 2 * np.dot(v2 - v1, -n) * (-n)
                    particle1.v = v1_new
                    particle2.v = v2_new
                    # above is an attempt to make particles collide with each other some parts #are stolen from chat gpt 


    def increment(self):
        self.coll_det()
        for particle in self.particles:
            particle.r += self.dt * particle.v  # Euler's method to get positions, perhaps there #is a better way? 

    def particle_positions(self):
        return [particle.r for particle in self.particles]

    def particle_color(self):
        return [particle.color for particle in self.particles]


sim = Sim()

for particle in sim.particles:
    particle.r = np.random.uniform([-sim.X/2, -sim.Y/2], [sim.X/2, sim.Y/2], size=2) # first #positions
    particle.v = np.array([np.random.uniform(50, -50), np.random.uniform(50, -50)])
    #first velocities
     
sim.particles[0].color = "red"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter([], [], s=0.01, alpha=0.5)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-sim.X/2, sim.X/2)
    ax.set_ylim(-sim.Y/2, sim.Y/2)
    return scatter,

def update(frame):
    sim.increment()
    positions = sim.particle_positions()
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-sim.X / 2, sim.X / 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-sim.Y / 2, sim.Y / 2)
    ax.scatter(*zip(*positions))
    plt.pause(0.01)  # Adjust pause time for better visualization

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=12000, init_func=init)
#animation stuff which I have no idea on how it works

plt.show()
```

When particles starts moving faster because of the collisions they start moving without making collisions.

Comment: That is several question in one. You need to be more focused (and split in different posts if needed). Question 1: You have a problem with detection collision: it assumes that the collision occurs at t+dt. When it could have occurred somewhere in between. You need to think in 3D (x,y,t). Does the cylinder (skewed cylinder, but still a cylinder) of base a circle of center (x₁(t), y₁(t), t) and radius rad₁, and axis (vx₁, vy₁, 1) (or (dt.vx₁, dt.vx₁, dt), that is the same), (therefore including circle (x₁(t+dt), y₁(d+td), t+dt)) intersects with cylinder (x₂(t), y₂(t), t), rad₂, axis (vx₂,vy₂,1).

Comment: Question 2:, you have a problem with integration scheme. What you are using is explicit Euler of 1st order. This is the one each geek kid rediscover when trying to reinvent numerical integration (I did, in the eighties, with planet simulation. Had the same stability vs speed problem). But other than that, we don't use it. For that exact reason: it is unstable, unless dt is insanely small.   You should at least try some implicit Euler, or Runge-Kuta.

Comment: Question 3: you have a problem with implementation. You are trying to do that nice scholar "OO" thing. But that prevents an efficient usage of numpy. If you are to use numpy (and you tagged this question numpy, so I guess this is what you want), then you need to do some batch computation. To have arrays of r, of v, of rad, etc. Not just one per particle, but one for the whole set. And do some vectorized computation on it. In other words, avoid at all cost any pure python for loop. For example, to pick the easy one, your Euler "increment" should just be "vectorX += vectorV*dt"

Comment: (`vectorX` being a (N,2) array, and so is `vectorV`, containing x,y coordinates of all particles, and x,y coordinates of all particle's speed)

Comment: Question 3 should be addressed last, of course. Conceptuals problem come before implementation ones. But we can't address all 3 question in one shot.

Comment: Also, side note (maybe related to your question): **be very careful of default value of parameters**. No problem when they are scalar (or just immutable) parameters. But with arrays... not forbidden, but you need to know what you are doing. And here, I don't think it is the case. See that small example: `def f(x=np.zeros((2,))): return x`, `v1=f()`, `v2=f()`, `v1[0]=12`, `print(v2)`... It is the same `np.zeros((2,))`, same vector for both. Pretty sure that is not the behavior you wanted. I you want to say "if parameter is not given, then a 0 vector is used", then, you should have `None`

Comment: as default value. And test that in the code. Using same example. `def f(x=None): return np.zeros((2,)) if x is None else x` behaves more as expected.

Comment: @chrslg thank you very much for your answers. I immediatly changed my euler with 4th order runge-kutta, not much seems to be chnaged. I will now try your other reccomendations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.